# If $R$ is a subring of $S$, then $R$ and $S$ have the same characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to show If $R$ is a subring of $S$, then $R$ and $S$ have the same characteristic.Can any one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your rings aren't unitary this isn't even true: consider $R = \{0,2\} \subset \mathbb{Z}/4 = S$.

If they are unitary then it is trivially true.

Comment: Actually it's still not true for rings with identity unless you require the subring to have the same identity.

Comment: @MattSamuel I don't recall ever seeing an author define a subring of an unitary ring without specifying that they must share the same identity. So yes, that it was I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Both rings have the same identity element